# Sharing AJAX call with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an input field. When the page is loaded, if input is pre-populated, then make AJAX call. Otherwise, wait until input field change to make AJAX call.

My AJAX call is quite complicated, so I want these two scenarios to share the same function.

Here is my implementation (pseudo code):

```
 function checkInput { $.ajax(... complex logic goes here ...); }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (!!$("#input").val()) {
      checkInput();    
    }
  });

  $("#input").change(checkInput());
```

Problem is, the function checkInput is invoked right away.

How can I avoid this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the function, don't invoke it

```
 $("#input").change(checkInput);
```

When you're doing `checkInput()` you are invoking the `checkInput` function. In JavaScript functions are first class objects, you can pass them around just like any other type.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ben. It explains a lot. I was scratching my head for couple hours now.

Comment: @AdamNYC Glad I could help! Note, this is in-fact what you're already doing when you're doing `$(document).ready` in `jQuery`, you're passing a function to it (to execute when the `DOM` is ready, the only difference is that that function is anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the function being invoked immediately is that the expression is evaluated when reached here:

```
$("#input").change(checkInput());
```

Note that the callback function `checkInput()` executes in order to be evaluated. Another approach would be to do this:

```
$("#input").change(function(){checkInput();});
```

Which will allow the function to be run when called instead of when first wired up as an event.

Comment: Thanks Travis. It makes a lot of sense too.